# NAV2016: How to specify filter criteria?

Tags: soap, navision

In Microsoft Navision 2016 we use SOAP requests to acces data (just reading, no updates) from a NodeJS application. The protocol used is direct SOAP requests.

The SOAP request we currently use is `resourceactivityentries`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
       xmlns:res="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/resourceactivityentries">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <res:ReadMultiple>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <res:filter>
            <res:Field></res:Field>
            <res:Criteria>?</res:Criteria>
         </res:filter>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:bookmarkKey></res:bookmarkKey>
         <res:setSize></res:setSize>
      </res:ReadMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to specify filter criteria to reduce the amount of data returned with a single request, e.g. limit to some `Prod_Order_No` as `100000*`?

Comment: Where does Microsoft provide the offical docs and specs for NAV16 SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your setSize node to the number of record nodes you want returned.